# How can I separate text from variable value in Posman

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, variables, postman

I try to separate text from variable value in Postman.

Value my variable:

```
{
"id": ObjectID("x1223123x"),
"name": "John",
"tokens": [{
    "type": "activation",
    "token": "xX-tokenValue"
}]}
```

I caught it with:

`const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());`
`pm.globals.set("textMongo", $( "textarea[name*='document']" ).text());`

I store it in text type because I separated it from html page.

When I try to parse it to json i have a problem:

```
console.log(JSON.parse($( "textarea[name*='document']" ).text()));
JSONError: No value found for key _id at 2:12 "id": ObjectID("x1223123x"),
```

Whatever... What can I do to store in new variable, value of "token": "xX-tokenValue" ??

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = pm.response.json();
if(res.tokens!=null && res.tokens.lenght>0)
{
  pm.globals.set("textMongo",res.tokens[0].token);
}
```

In your case, the response is in JSON format, so you don't need to use String functions to get your token.

Comment: As i wrote before, my response is html. I separated part of html to variable as String. Now i want to transform value that variable to JSON an then pull token value.